# What is wrong with this benchmarking script?

Tags: php, sqlite

I've written a small php script to benchmark the performance of our various LAMP servers. I'm doing the test on speed of various factors such as disk I/O, database I/O, etc.

In the script, I'm first creating a random string of 100KB called $payload.

For Disk I/O check, I'm writing $payload to disk for 1000 times using file_put_contents() which completes in a few milliseconds.

Secondly, by using same logic for sqlite check, I'm inserting 1000 records of $payload string in an sqlite table. Shouldn't they take the same amount of time? But this sqlite inserts goes on for everrr. Any idea why?

```
for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) //generate a big string
{
    $n=rand(0,57)+65;
    $payload = $payload.chr($n);
}
//write test:
$start = microtime(true);
    if ($type=='disk') // Disk I/O -> This takes only a few msecs.
    {
        for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) file_put_contents($fname,$payload);
    }
    else if ($type=='sqlite') //sqlite test -> This keeps running for everrrrrr.....
    {
        $db = new SQLite3("benchmark.db");
        $db->exec('create table temp(t text)');
        for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
            $db->exec("insert into temp values('{$payload}')");
            };

    }
$wtime=round((microtime(true) - $start)*1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are not using explicit transactions, SQLite will wrap an automatic transaction around every statement.

To guarantee that a transaction is durable, the database has to flush the data to disk at the end of each transaction.
This implies that it waits for the disk write to complete before continuing.

To make the database check similar to the disk check, execute `$db->exec("pragma synchronous = off")` after creating the DB.

However, you wouldn't want to use this setting in a real database where you'd care about data loss.
Wrap `$db->exec("begin")` and `$db->exec("commit")` around the loop to use a single transaction for all writes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved it (Unfortunately, I can't upvote since I don't have the rep yet). SQLite writes now only take 3349 msecs compared to 3500 of disk I/O.